# Angular 2 component inside KnockoutJS component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js, angular, angular-components

So I have a website written KnockoutJS that can be extended by other team's plugins. I am trying to allow those teams to use whatever library/framework they want. Some of them want to use Angular 2. What I am trying to do is create a KnockoutJS component that will act as a wrapper around an Angular 2 component (the name of which can be passed in as a parameter). From my investigation, there doesn't appear to be a clean, native way to bootstrap an Angular 2 app on a specific section on DOM like there is with Knockout's applyBindings and Angular 1's $compile. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Don't do it! Don't mix KnockoutJS and Angular (1 _or_ 2) in one website. It's a path to madness.

Comment: *If* you could apply Angular2 to just the component, you would need a custom binding handler for it, not a wrapping KO component. Any DOM-manipulating code needs to be in a binding handler.